# Allow python module import from a different module

Tags: python, python-import

I have a python project with following structure:

```
app/
    api/
        __init__.py
    core
        __init__.py
        impl.py
```

`impl` module contains some implementation such as `Car` and it can be imported as:
`from app.core.impl import Car`

However, I am trying to make it so that the class can be imported from `api` module like:
`from app.api import Car`

I have tried adding this to `api/__init__.py` file:
`from app.core.impl import Car`, but this doesn't work. Any ideas ?

Comment: Works for me if I add `from app.core.impl import Car` to api/__init__.py (you have a typo)

Comment: Have you tried importing core to api i.e   in api `from .core import *`

Comment: @EkureEdem I'm trying to avoid importing entire namespace.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @fferri. This should work.  Perhaps the error I'm getting is due to packing issues and incorrectly installing in remote machines via pip